# i am lost how do i attach clothes to this character it is clipping out when i attach them how do i fix it

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, rigging

[image]I have been stuck on this for weeks I don't know what to do please help me

here is the character that I am trying to attach clothes to

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1y7cD74z12RPjHcyU-lvlk25dvGHo_v0t

hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First make sure that you're in *Rest Pose*: in *Pose* mode you can select all your bones and press <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, or press the *Rest Position* button in the *Properties* panel > *Data* (then press back *Pose Position* button).
- You need to remove a lot of overlaying vertices, so select your cloth mesh, go in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>W</kbd> > Remove Doubles. Increase the *Merge Distance* value on the bottom of the *Tools* panel (on the left of the 3D View).
- Same thing for the rest of the character, remove doubles.
- Now enable the *Proportional Editing* option on the bottom bar of the 3D View, and move the cloth vertices until it fits the arm. Actually you'd better have a proper topology to do this operation, i.e. quads and not thousands of tris.
- Also select your armature and in *Edit* mode make the bones fit the arm.
- Select your character meshes, then the armature, and parent the character meshes with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *With Automatic Weight*.
- It works.

[image]